# Data Points not fully shown Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import style
style.use("dark_background")

tips = sb.load_dataset("tips")
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sb.set_context('paper', font_scale=1.2)
sb.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", data=tips,markers=['o', '^'], 
          scatter_kws={'s':50, "linewidth" : 0.2, "edgecolor" : 'w'}, aspect=1.5)
```

I am using dataset tips(seaborn dataset). When am plotting the graph some data points are not fully shown like one at (0,1) the triangle data point is not fully shown and other at (51,10) the circle data point is half visible.

Graph : [Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9LaP.png)

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_xlim()` in such a case. You can use `ax.set_xlim()` to expand the area over which the image is displayed. Also, seaborn gives priority to height and aspect ratio over figsize.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import style
style.use("dark_background")

tips = sb.load_dataset("tips")
# plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sb.set_context('paper', font_scale=1.2)
sb.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", data=tips,markers=['o', '^'], 
          scatter_kws={'s':50, "linewidth" : 0.2, "edgecolor" : 'w'}, aspect=2, legend_out=False, height=4)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim((0,55))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you r-beginners it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the correct answer by @r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618484/1356000), you can pass `clip_on=False` to the plotting function to prevent artists to being clipped at the edge of the axes.

```py
sb.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", data=tips,markers=['o', '^'], 
          scatter_kws={'s':50, "linewidth" : 0.2, "edgecolor" : 'w', 'clip_on':False}, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Diziet Asahi this helped me a lot.